# Multiple developers working on same Web Application Project

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

I have a team of three developers working on the same Web Application Project web site. We are all using VS 2010 and Source Gear Vault.

Each of us has a different working folder on our local drives and I am encountering some issues I need to understand:

1) When one of use wants to add a new page to the project, it appears that we must check out the entire project or at least the .csproj file, add the page and then check the .csproj file back in. Is this correct?

2) When we checkin the changed code, we must not checkin the bin folder or anything in it. If we do, nobody else can compile their code. Again, is this correct?

Bottom line, I am looking for some best practices advice. What is the best way to manage this development effort given the tools we are using?

Comment: Consider using "Edit/Merge/Commit" instead of the default but rather antiquated "Check Out/Edit/Check In" method. You can find these under Concurrent Development Style on the Vault Options. But do understand what this change entails. No more checkouts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The only thing that should be checked out when adding the new page is the .csproj file.  On checkin, you will commit the csproj file (edit) and the new page files (add)

2)Your bin should not be under source control.  If you require a build for deploy, you can either use VS's Publish dialog locally against the latest code set or you can automate the builds from a build machine (via MSBUILD) that will compile your project from source control.

Comment: Steve is right on with the fact that the BIN folder should never be under source control and by default it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

1) This is not necessary, if you add files to the project directory they will show up and your project files will be updated. At my company, we have a policy of not checking in any form of config file (be it web.config or project files). We mark them as read/write and don't worry about them. For web.config, we maintain a master version, which is not pulled, but stores all possible values.

2) As the bin contains compiled code, if someone is working on part of that compiled code, they would not want to get the dll. Again, at my company, we usually will compile our own versions and do not check in files in the bin.

Comment: -1: Your first statement is not true for "web application projects"..  It would be accurate for "web site projects" which are a wholely different beast.

Comment: usually .... do not check in fines in the bin? These should never be committed to source control. If you have a binary that needs to be shared, put it in its own folder (and check that in) and copy the file to the BIN folder as part of your build.